# Firebase V9: export 'default' not found in my Firebase loader

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am working on a React project with Firebase (^9.6.7) and while I am configuring the Firebase database it shows such an error:

> Compiled with problems: ERROR in ./src/App.js 28:4-17
>
> export 'default' (imported as 'db') was not found in './firebase' (possible exports: auth, db, storage)

```js
// in firebase.js 
// v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
    
const firebaseApp = firebase.initialzeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCAxk5u3dc69u-OeGuQfR8IZYoj3dr1Kxo",
  authDomain: "myinstagram-clone-fb535.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "myinstagram-clone-fb535",
  storageBucket: "myinstagram-clone-fb535.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1061340472237",
  appId: "1:1061340472237:web:d0b42559484d699a85b724",
  measurementId: "G-9H2TSBPRSK"
});
      
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();
export { db, auth, storage }
```

```js
// in app.js
import db from './firebase' // <- error here
```

Comment: If you are going to use `firebaseApp.firestore()`, you may as well do the same for `firebaseApp.auth()` and `firebaseApp.storage()` for consistency.

Comment: if it's a new project, you should really be using modular version for smaller package size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no `export default XXXX` statement in your code.

To correctly import the `db` object you exported using

```
export { db, auth, storage }
```

you must use

```
import { db } from './firebase'
```

Comment: I applied this one before but the page is not loading instead it shows a blank page

Comment: @GolamrabbaniRocky A blank page doesn't indicate this fix didn't work, but that you have a new issue to deal with that is unrelated to this one. When you load your app in a browser, check the browser console for details about the new issue.